# Suspend function 'delay' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Tags: kotlin

Hi am trying to run following kotlin code:

**Code Snippet 1**

This is not working
with the error:
`function 'delay' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

```
package kotlinx.coroutines.guide.exampleBasic02

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch {echoWorldWrapper() }
    println("Hello")
}


suspend fun echoWorldWrapper() {

   echoWorld()
}

  fun echoWorld() {
    delay(1000L)
    println("World!")
}
```

However following works:
**Code Snippet 2:**

```
package kotlinx.coroutines.guide.exampleBasic02

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch {echoWorldWrapper() }
    println("Hello")
}


suspend fun echoWorldWrapper() {

    delay(1000L)
    println("World!")
}
```

In my production code I can only follow **Code Snippet 1**. Is there any workaround for approach 1 to work. I am new to Kotlin and couldn't find any other answer to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to call a suspend function from a function that is not also a suspend function. `suspend` carries with it under the hood the state of a coroutine in a Continuation object. `delay()` cannot operate without that coroutine to work with.

The functionality of `delay()` is to *suspend* a coroutine for a period of time and then resume it. It doesn't make any sense for it to be called from a non-suspend function, because that means there is no coroutine to suspend.

The alternative for a non-suspend function is to use `Thread.sleep()`, which will block the thread for a period of time. Example:

```
//Use withContext to make it acceptable to call a blocking function in a coroutine
suspend fun echoWorldWrapper() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   echoWorld()
}

// A blocking function:
fun echoWorld() {
    Thread.sleep(1000L)
    println("World!")
}
```

Comment: In my case `echoWorld()` is overriden so I can't make it suspend. What if I use another `runBlocking` eg. `fun echoWorld() = runBlocking {`. That would that mean a coroutine inside coroutine, I guess its a bad idea...

Comment: So why not use `Thread.sleep()` instead of `delay()`? That's all you'd be effectively doing by wrapping it in `runBlocking()`, but with fewer steps. Of course, I don't know what's actually calling `echoWorld()` to know whether it's acceptable to block the thread. Do you have to call this overridden function from within a coroutine? If that's the case, in your coroutine use `suspend fun echoWorldWrapper() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { echoWorld() }`. It is acceptable to call a blocking funtion on Dispatchers.Default.

Comment: Huh?  Dispatchers.IO is the one typically used for blocking.  In any event, yes, this is a bad idea, and usually the correct approach is to redesign your code so `echoWorld` _can_ be a `suspend fun`, e.g. by changing the supertype's method to also be `suspend`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman IO is for IO-bound blocking, and Default is for CPU-bound blocking. In this case, though, I think it's right that IO is more appropriate.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Could you please give an example where we can call `echoWorld()` which is using `delay` without using `suspend`. `suspend fun echoWorldWrapper() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { echoWorld() }`  isn't working assuming `echoWorld()` is not using `suspend`.

Comment: I cannot give an example of that because it's impossible. I thought my answer explained that it is impossible. It doesn't make sense to delay in a function that is not a suspend function. There is no coroutine to delay if it's not a suspend function. The quoted code in your comment is intended for use if you replace `delay()` with `Thread.sleep()`. But as pointed out in the other comment, you should use Dispatchers.IO rather than Dispatchers.Default.